# how can use weight attribute for different weight

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, product-attribute, price-rules

I am seeking 2 answers from various Magento forum since last 1 week, but not getting any reply. Don't know why, maybe my question is absurd or foolish, but at least I shall know I am wrong. I hope somebody will show me right way of possibilities.

**I have 2 questions:**
1. What is the use of Weight Attribute, we get while adding/editing Product. 
And where it affect in store. Can I use this any way to calculate the price of products? [image: See the image]

2. Just need suggestion what will be the right way to handle following scenario;

   Product Name-Tomato
   Different available Weights:
   100g is of $10.75,
   200g is of $21.50,
   250g is of $32.25 and
   500g is of $53.75

   And Qty may be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 up to 20.

   So, Now if buyer buy 3 Qty of 500g then the calculation will be $53.75 x 3 = $161.25 and this amount should display on product detail page (when buyer select his/her requirement) and in cart page.

My doubt is How I will set 4 different weights in 1 single Wight Attribute Text Box.

i also would like to describe that can we add the suggestion on checkout page that so customer can add more product in other product aswell .help would be highly appreciated .....thanks

Comment: Weight Attribute is basically used for shipping purpose.Many shipping method works on  Weight,dimension and destination .Which version you are using of Magento ??

Comment: Your problem fixed via configurable products and it is manage easy to single attribute. If your need any help let me know .

Comment: @Arunendra I am learning Magento 1.9, so if my shipping is FREE then can I keep the value of Weight as 0 (zero).

Comment: @Abdul Thank you very much for your kind consideration. I also learnt that configurable product can solve my problem. But I wonder how I will add this product in product list. I confused how I will add drop down for weight and a text box for Qty and finally the formula for calculating the price. I will obliged for your  help & support.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the configurable products with the weight option choice.
 For these goals you must create your attribute, **weight_of_tomato** with a dropdown type and Global scope.
 At result your buyers get the opportunity choose an option with price and another advantages.
The downside to this method is more difficult process of producing goods and a slight increase in the load, compared usual products. How else one option you can use Custom options. 
But they are significantly limited in its functionality. However, there are modules that extend them to the extent necessary for you (for example Advanced Product Options)